# Как заставить работать python программу с БД Django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

У меня в наличии:

1. Python программа, которая обрабатывает `csv` файлы.
   Результат одной из обработок:

```json
{'username': 'resplendent', 'spend_money': 451731, 'gems': {'Танзанит', 'Рубин', 'Сапфир'}}
{'username': 'bellwether', 'spend_money': 217794, 'gems': {'Петерсит', 'Сапфир'}}
```

2. У меня есть БД (идёт вместе с Django проектом), с которой я взаимодействую либо через Django Rest API, либо через админку.

**Проблема**: 
Нет идей, как обработать `csv` файл, попавший в бд.

Comment: А в чем вопрос?.. не совсем понятно. Python программа и проект Django 'это два разных приложения? Правильно я понимаю? Вам нужно их поженить вместе? В этом задача?

Comment: @МихаилРебров, совершенно верно. Не понятно как их свести.

Comment: ну это смотря что за программа под номером 1. CSV в виде строки я думаю она тоже сможет скушать? Данные можно через REST API взять. Вопрос только в программе этой. Не думаю что она прям сильно большая...может она и в вопрос поместится? ну или ссылка на гитхаб может где завалялась?

Comment: @МихаилРебров, прога кушает сам csv файл, формирует из него список и уже дальше обрабатывает. https://github.com/3XTR4OS/JuniorTestTask/blob/main/csv_handler.py

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте сделать модели в которые вы будете записывать результат работы csv  файла а потом уже с конкретным полем модели работать.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы (либо публикуйте подобные сообщения как комментарии). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]